# Draw an ordered hierarchy using Graphviz

Tags: data-structures, hierarchy, graphviz

I have an ordered hierarchy which I'd like to plot using Graphviz (or some other visualisation program).

Ideally the plot would draw the leading and trailing vector of a node and maintain the correct level in the hierarchy. What I'm most unsure of is how to maintain the levels of hierarchy since trailing vectors can return to their superior/parent.

If it is unclear what exactly I am asking for then at 47 minutes of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWgDk-o-6ZE there is a picture in the presentation.

I'd like to know if it is possible and what the graphviz (.gv) file might look like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [Prolog program](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/tree/master/genealogy) to produce genealogical 'trees', like this one

[image]

Here the DB is small, but it works fairly well for larger data sets... the .gv computed by the program, submitted to Graphviz for rendering:

```
digraph "graph_window" {
 node [
  style = "radial"
  fillcolor = "white"
  shape = "ellipse"
  label = ""
 ]
 edge [
  arrowhead = "vee"
 ]
 subgraph "1" {
   rank = "same"
   rankdir = "LR"
  subgraph "['Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Claude Bowes-Lyon']" {
   "'Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck'" [
     fillcolor = "white:red"
     label = "Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck"
   ]
   "'Claude Bowes-Lyon'" [
     fillcolor = "white:green"
     label = "Claude Bowes-Lyon"
   ]
  }
  subgraph "['George V','Princess Mary of Teck']" {
   "'George V'" [
     fillcolor = "white:green"
     label = "George V"
   ]
   "'Princess Mary of Teck'" [
     fillcolor = "white:red"
     label = "Princess Mary of Teck"
   ]
  }
 }
 subgraph "2" {
   rank = "same"
   rankdir = "LR"
  subgraph "['George VI','Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon']" {
   "'George VI'" [
     fillcolor = "white:green"
     label = "George VI"
   ]
   "'Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon'" [
     fillcolor = "white:red"
     label = "Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon"
   ]
  }
  "'Rose Bowes-Lyon'" [
    fillcolor = "white:red"
    label = "Rose Bowes-Lyon"
  ]
 }
 subgraph "3" {
   rank = "same"
   rankdir = "LR"
  "'Elizabeth II'" [
    fillcolor = "white:red"
    label = "Elizabeth II"
  ]
 }
 "['George V','Princess Mary of Teck']" [
   shape = "point"
   width = "0.1"
   height = "0.1"
 ]
 "['Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Claude Bowes-Lyon']" [
   shape = "point"
   width = "0.1"
   height = "0.1"
 ]
 "['George VI','Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon']" [
   shape = "point"
   width = "0.1"
   height = "0.1"
 ]
 "'George V'" -> "['George V','Princess Mary of Teck']" [
 ]
 "'Princess Mary of Teck'" -> "['George V','Princess Mary of Teck']" [
 ]
 "['George V','Princess Mary of Teck']" -> "'George VI'" [
 ]
 "'Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck'" -> "['Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Claude Bowes-Lyon']" [
 ]
 "'Claude Bowes-Lyon'" -> "['Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Claude Bowes-Lyon']" [
 ]
 "['Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Claude Bowes-Lyon']" -> "'Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon'" [
 ]
 "['Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Claude Bowes-Lyon']" -> "'Rose Bowes-Lyon'" [
 ]
 "'George VI'" -> "['George VI','Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon']" [
 ]
 "'Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon'" -> "['George VI','Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon']" [
 ]
 "['George VI','Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon']" -> "'Elizabeth II'" [
 ]
}
```

that is, each layer goes into its own subgraph. I further used the subgraph to group pairs of parents.